# Google Chrome has installed in Dutch language (using Windows 10)

Tags: language

Since the language is one that I don't understand, and the layout of the 'settings' seems  different to the proposed answer- I cannot guess where to go next. I have changes the language in some individual pages eg Web Store, but it goes back to Dutch on restarting the browser!

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Hamburgerlike button in the top right hand corner.

Go to Settings (Should be 5th from the bottom)

Click Advanced Settings (Last Option on the page, should be blue like a link.)

Click on Language and Input Settings (Under Language, above Downloads, above a checkbox)

There will be a list of installed languages. If English is not there, click Add (bottom left-hand corner)

Scroll through the options until you find English. Select it and click OK

Make sure English is selected, click Done at the bottom right hand corner.

Restart Chrome.